# IJKplayer craches on play some video

Tags: java, android, media-player

I use [IjkPlayer](https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer).

Most of the videos that I tried played ok, But one type cause the app to crashes and show this

```
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x2c in tid 13026
```

I think it because the video has no sound. this is the details of the video

```
    Duration: 00:51:17.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(heb): Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 1024x768, 491 kb/s, 15 tbr,       1k tbn, 1k tbc
```

If someone knows how to fix this I will very appreciate this.

Comment: It is a crash in native library (i.e. the library built using NDK). It is maybe because the library doesn't support the video type you are trying to play and crashing.

Comment: It support I found the problem in one of the C files.. thanks

Comment: gr8, post the solution here, so that it will help other ppl.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Can you explain where you change audio_cached_duration to -1.  In method ffp_check_buffering_l I have 

        int64_t audio_cached_duration = -1;

Comment: Would you like to send me Apk file?! I couldn't find and build apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it has been long time ago. But the solution is

Their is problem in the file ff_ffplay.c in the ffp_check_buffering_l function. if I change audio_cached_duration to be -1 it works!

maybe it can help someone..

Comment: i have so file how can i change it and fix mine

Comment: I have tried it but not resolved